# MediaWiki WikiEditor Toolbar Height Size 100%

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mediawiki

I have just run the update.php script in the maintenance folder of MediaWiki. I am now having a problem with the WikiEditor Toolbar Height. It seems to be 100% of the height of the page. You can see the problem here: http://tmltesting.com/w/index.php?title=vv&action=edit. I have tried disabling all extensions and the problem still persists. I have been trying for a while to fix the problem but I am unsure what is causing it.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix it? I am running MediaWiki 1.24.1 and WikiEditor 0.4.0. Thanks in advance. There also seems to be an extra output at the top of the page (blank line) after loading. Not sure if this may have something to do with it.

Picture: http://i57.tinypic.com/avsoyx.jpg

This is exactly what I did prior to the problem starting:

1) Added PageDisqus extension with following code to LocalSettings.php:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/PageDisqus/PageDisqus.php";
$wgPageDisqusShortname = 'Shortname';
#Exclude
$wgPageDisqusExclude = array(".+:.+");
```

2) This is when the problem began. The problem stopped when I removed the above code so I fixed it by adding the following code around the above code:

```
if (($_GET['action'] != 'edit') && ($_GET['action'] != 'submit') && ($_GET['redirect'] != 'no')) {
}
```

3) This fixed the problem so I went ahead and downloaded the MediaWiki language package and added the following code to the LocalSettings.php Including the show error code):

```
#Show errors
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;

#LANGUAGE --START--

$EXT = "$IP/extensions";
require_once "$EXT/Babel/Babel.php";

require_once "$EXT/cldr/cldr.php";

require_once "$EXT/CleanChanges/CleanChanges.php";
$wgCCTrailerFilter = true;
$wgCCUserFilter = false;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usenewrc'] = 1;

require_once "$EXT/LocalisationUpdate/LocalisationUpdate.php";
$wgLocalisationUpdateDirectory = "$IP/cache";

require_once "$EXT/Translate/Translate.php";
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-messagereview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-groupreview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-import'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['pagetranslation'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['translate-manage'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['translator']['skipcaptcha'] = true; // Bug 34182: needed with ConfirmEdit
$wgTranslateDocumentationLanguageCode = 'qqq';
$wgExtraLanguageNames['qqq'] = 'Message documentation'; # No linguistic content. Used for documenting messages

require_once "$EXT/UniversalLanguageSelector/UniversalLanguageSelector.php";
#LANGUAGE --END--
```

4) Ran the update.php script as it states to do during installation.

5) Removed this line of code from the LocalisationUpdate file 'LocalisationCache.php' line 559 because it was producing an error:

```
            // throw new MWException( __METHOD__ . ": Invalid JSON file: $fileName" );
```

6) Then noticed the problem again. I removed the code from LocalSettings.php (all of it including a few previous working extensions) and the problem is still there.

7) Replacing the code removed from 'LocalisationCache.php' also does not fix the problem.

8) Editing anything in the following code from 'jquery.wikiEditor.toolbar.css' just seems to remove the toolbar altogether. Even after reverting back the toolbar does not appear. I have to re-upload the file:

```
/* Top Level Containers */
.wikiEditor-ui-toolbar .tabs,
.wikiEditor-ui-toolbar .section-main {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-height: 26px;
    height: 100%;
```

I am confused.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: I don't see any problem with the site. And btw.: The update script nly changes the database schema, so if you haven't updated the extension/mediawik core itself, it seems impossible that the css was changed due to the update script :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Florian. So you son't see the blue box that I see in this picture? http://tinypic.com/r/avsoyx/8 , I have tried it on multiple computers, devices and browsers and get the same result.

Comment: No, i don't see that. But that's the case, if you have some unexpected output on the page, e.g. a notice error or some text added via "echo" in some extension. Can you check your LocalSettings.php for such output's?

Comment: Hi Florian, I have checked and do not notice anthing that could be outputting. I have added some more information above.  Would me posting the whole LocalSettings code help?

Answer (score 0):

Please find

```
.wikiEditor-ui-toolbar .tabs, .wikiEditor-ui-toolbar .section-main {
 position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-height: 26px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and change height to

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply cNb, I have played around with this yesterday. (See 8 above) I have also just tried your suggestion. It removed the toolbar altogether. Its strange. I have added some more information above about how the problem started.